# why tkinter message box didn't show up when i call them?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I started to learn python and interested to make simple tic tac toe game with GUI using tkinter but I have some problems here when player reach the goal, the code :

```
from tkinter import  *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

#some code in here for button and other

if X9+X1+X5  == 3 or X1+X2+X3 == 3 or X4+X5+X6 == 3 or X7+X8+X9 == 3 or X7+X5+X3 == 3 or X1+X4+X7 == 3 or X2+X5+X8 == 3 or X3+X6+X9 == 3 :#X1-X9 variables for X coordinates
    messagebox.showinfo("X win !!!!", "Congrats X win") #win message X and goals

elif O1+O5+O9 == 3 or O1+O2+O3 == 3 or O4+O5+O6 == 3 or O7+O8+O9 == 3 or O7+O5+O3 == 3 or O1+O4+O7 == 3 or O2+O5+O8 == 3 or O3+O6+O9 == 3:#O1-O9 variables for O coordinates and goals
    messagebox.showinfo("O win !!!!", "Congrats O win")#win message for O
else :
    messagebox.showinfo("Draw", "Draw") #draw message
```

but when I run and get X-X-X or O-O-O the message box didn't come, and then I put one button for confirm like this and it works, but that is not what I expect for this program.

```
def result():
    if X9+X1+X5  == 3 or X1+X2+X3 == 3 or X4+X5+X6 == 3 or X7+X8+X9 == 3 or X7+X5+X3 == 3 or X1+X4+X7 == 3 or X2+X5+X8 == 3 or X3+X6+X9 == 3 :
        messagebox.showinfo("X win !!!!", "Congrats X win")

    elif O1+O5+O9 == 3 or O1+O2+O3 == 3 or O4+O5+O6 == 3 or O7+O8+O9 == 3 or O7+O5+O3 == 3 or O1+O4+O7 == 3 or O2+O5+O8 == 3 or O3+O6+O9 == 3:
        messagebox.showinfo("O win !!!!", "Congrats O win")
    else :
        messagebox.showinfo("Draw", "Draw")
button10 = Button(top, text="Enter", width = 10, command = result ).place(x = 107, y = 300)
```

Anyone know how to show the message without calling them with button?

full code :

```
from tkinter import  *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox 

O1=X1=O2=X2=O3=X3=O4=X4=O5=X5=O6=X6=O7=X7=O8=X8=O9=X9=0
count = 0

def printXO1():
    global count
    global X1
    global O1
    count = count + 1
    if count % 2 == 0:
        button1.set("O")
        O1 = O1 + 1 
    else :
        button1.set("X")
        X1 = X1+1
    return count, X1, O1    
        

def printXO2():
    global count
    global X2
    global O2
    count = count + 1
    if count % 2 == 0:
        button2.set("O")
        O2 = O2 + 1
    else :
        button2.set("X")
        X2 = X2 + 1
    return count, X2, O2
    

def printXO3():
    global count
    global X3
    global O3
    count = count + 1
    if count % 2 == 0:  
        button3.set("O")
        O3 = O3 + 1
    else :
        button3.set("X")
        X3 = X3 +1
    return count, X3, O3

def printXO4():
    global count
    global X4
    global O4
    count = count + 1
    if count % 2 == 0:
        button4.set("O")
        O4 = O4 + 1 
    else :
        button4.set("X")
        X4 = X4 + 1
    return count, X2, O2

def printXO5():
    global count
    global X5
    global O5
    count = count + 1
    if count % 2 == 0:  
        button5.set("O")
        O5 = O5 + 1
    else :
        button5.set("X")
        X5 = X5 + 1
    return count, X5, O5
def printXO6():
    global count
    global X6
    global O6
    count = count + 1
    if count % 2 == 0:
        button6.set("O")
        O6 = O6 + 1
    else :
        button6.set("X")
        X6 = X6 + 1
    return count, X6, O6
def printXO7():
    global count
    global X7
    global O7
    count = count + 1
    if count % 2 == 0:
        button7.set("O")
        O7 = O7 + 1
    else :
        button7.set("X")
        X7 = X7 + 1
    return count, X7, O7


def printXO8():
    global count
    global X8
    global O8
    count = count + 1
    if count % 2 == 0:
        button8.set("O")
        O8 = O8 + 1
    else :
        button8.set("X")
        X8 = X8 + 1
    return count, X8, O8

def printXO9():
    global count
    global X9
    global O9
    count = count + 1
    if count % 2 == 0:
        button9.set("O") 
        O9 = O9 + 1
    else :
        button9.set("X")
        X9 = X9 + 1
    return count, X9, O9

top = tk.Tk()
top.geometry("300x350")

button1 = tk.StringVar()
button = tk.Button(top, textvariable = button1 , width = 10, height = 5, command =printXO1 ).place(x = 17, y = 10 )
button1.set(" ")

button2 = tk.StringVar()
button = Button(top, textvariable = button2 , width = 10, height = 5, command =printXO2 ).place(x = 107, y = 10 )
button2.set(" ")

button3 = tk.StringVar()
button = Button(top, textvariable = button3 , width = 10, height = 5, command =printXO3 ).place(x = 197, y = 10 )
button3.set(" ")

button4 = tk.StringVar()
button = Button(top, textvariable = button4 , width = 10, height = 5, command =printXO4 ).place(x = 17, y = 107 )
button4.set(" ")

button5 = tk.StringVar()
button = Button(top, textvariable = button5 , width = 10, height = 5, command =printXO5 ).place(x = 107, y = 107 )
button5.set(" ")

button6= tk.StringVar()
button = Button(top, textvariable = button6 , width = 10, height = 5, command =printXO6 ).place(x = 197, y = 107 )
button6.set(" ")

button7 = tk.StringVar()
button = Button(top, textvariable = button7 , width = 10, height = 5, command =printXO7 ).place(x = 17, y = 200 )
button7.set(" ")

button8 = tk.StringVar()
button = Button(top, textvariable = button8 , width = 10, height = 5, command =printXO8 ).place(x = 107, y = 200 )
button8.set(" ")

button9 = tk.StringVar()
button = Button(top, textvariable = button9 , width = 10, height = 5, command =printXO9 ).place(x = 197, y = 200 )
button9.set(" ")

def result():

    if X9+X1+X5  == 3 or X1+X2+X3 == 3 or X4+X5+X6 == 3 or X7+X8+X9 == 3 or X7+X5+X3 == 3 or X1+X4+X7 == 3 or X2+X5+X8 == 3 or X3+X6+X9 == 3 :
        messagebox.showinfo("X win !!!!", "Congrats X win")

    elif O1+O5+O9 == 3 or O1+O2+O3 == 3 or O4+O5+O6 == 3 or O7+O8+O9 == 3 or O7+O5+O3 == 3 or O1+O4+O7 == 3 or O2+O5+O8 == 3 or O3+O6+O9 == 3:
        messagebox.showinfo("O win !!!!", "Congrats O win")
    else :
        messagebox.showinfo("Draw", "Draw")
button10 = Button(top, text="Enter", width = 10, command = result ).place(x = 107, y = 300)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Firstly, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), show your entire code as to how the X and O are being entered. If you are using keyboard input for the values then you can try to bind the key press event with the result function something like this `root.bind_all('<Key>', result)`, so that the check happens every time a value is entered

Comment: @AST I make 9 button that show X and O text when i click, for examples i click button1 using mouse for X then my X1 value change from 0 to 1 so when i got 3 X in rows for examples X1,X5,X9, i sum them and give a value 3 so the winner is X. But there's nothing happen, nothing message box showed.

Comment: Alright got you, so basically all the 9 buttons call a function to change the text on the button, depending on the player that clicks it, right? One way could be to add a function call `result()` at the end of the function(s) called by these 9 buttons so that the win check happens every time any button is clicked. And as I said previously please provide your entire code (or reasonable part of it) so that I can make an answer by referring to that.

Comment: @AST can you check it, there's the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code and made it shorter and more optimized. Refer to the code below:

```py
from tkinter import  *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox 

def printXO(index):
    global count,varx,buttons,varo
    button=buttons[index]
    count+=1
    if count % 2 == 0:
        button.config(text="O",state='disabled')
        varo[index] =+ 1
    else :
        button.config(text="X",state='disabled')
        varx[index] =+ 1
    print(count)
    result()

def result():
    o_count=0
    for o in varo:
        o_count+=o
    x_count=0
    for x in varx:
        x_count+=x

    if (o_count>=2 and x_count>=3) or (o_count>=3 and x_count>=2):

        if varx[8]+varx[0]+varx[4]  == 3 or varx[0]+varx[1]+varx[2] == 3 or varx[3]+varx[4]+varx[5] == 3 or varx[6]+varx[7]+varx[8] == 3 or varx[6]+varx[4]+varx[2] == 3 or varx[0]+varx[3]+varx[6] == 3 or varx[1]+varx[4]+varx[7] == 3 or varx[2]+varx[5]+varx[8] == 3 :
            messagebox.showinfo("X win !!!!", "Congrats X win")

        elif varo[0]+varo[4]+varo[8] == 3 or varo[0]+varo[1]+varo[2] == 3 or varo[3]+varo[4]+varo[5] == 3 or varo[6]+varo[7]+varo[8] == 3 or varo[6]+varo[4]+varo[2] == 3 or varo[0]+varo[3]+varo[6] == 3 or varo[1]+varo[4]+varo[7] == 3 or varo[2]+varo[5]+varo[8] == 3:
            messagebox.showinfo("O win !!!!", "Congrats O win")
        elif count==9 :
            messagebox.showinfo("Draw", "Draw")

top = tk.Tk()
top.geometry("300x350")

button1 = tk.Button(top, width = 10, height = 5, command =lambda: printXO(0) )
button1.place(x = 17, y = 10 )
button2 = tk.Button(top, width = 10, height = 5, command =lambda: printXO(1) )
button2.place(x = 107, y = 10 )
button3 = tk.Button(top, width = 10, height = 5, command =lambda: printXO(2) )
button3.place(x = 197, y = 10 )
button4 = tk.Button(top, width = 10, height = 5, command =lambda: printXO(3) )
button4.place(x = 17, y = 107 )
button5 = tk.Button(top, width = 10, height = 5, command =lambda: printXO(4) )
button5.place(x = 107, y = 107 )
button6 = tk.Button(top, width = 10, height = 5, command =lambda: printXO(5) )
button6.place(x = 197, y = 107 )
button7 = tk.Button(top, width = 10, height = 5, command =lambda: printXO(6) )
button7.place(x = 17, y = 200 )
button8 = tk.Button(top, width = 10, height = 5, command =lambda: printXO(7) )
button8.place(x = 107, y = 200 )
button9 = tk.Button(top, width = 10, height = 5, command =lambda: printXO(8) )
button9.place(x = 197, y = 200 )

count = 0
buttons=[button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,button6,button7,button8,button9]
varx=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
varo=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

top.mainloop()
```

Notes:

- I have initialized 2 lists containing the x and o values, that reduces the number of variables and you can now work with indices.
- There is no need to have a `StringVar()` in your case, you can use the `.config()` method to change the values. I have put all the button instances in a list so that they can be accessed by indices in the program.
- Having done these, there is no need to have those many functions, here I have created a function `printXO()` which takes in `index` as the parameter which is sent by the function call in the button.
- The buttons have the command as `lambda:printXO(<index>)` this allows us to call the function when needed with the parameter index, here the index  parameter will correspond to the button and hence the same association can be used with the lists `varo` and `varx` for changing the respective values.
- In the function `printXO()` I have changed the button state to `disabled` so as to prevent multiple clicks on the same button. the function `result()` has been called at the end so that the result check can happen after every button press.
- Finally, the function `result()` has a condition to check if there are minimum 5 moves made in the game (3 by x and 2 by o (or) 2 by x and 3 by o). Also, the `draw` `messagebox` will only appear if all the 9 moves have been made in the game.

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thank you bro, for your suggestions and the changes. I can learn more about python coding in effective ways.